# Write to Kusto ADX with spark connector -Performance Observations

Tags: apache-spark, azure-data-explorer

We have a use-case where we receive large volume of data (i.e., 80 GB divided into 300 files comes every 5 mins) in ADLS-V2 and using  spark-connector to write from ADLS-V2 to Kusto table.
During the write stage, noticed multiple cores are used to batch the entire data and only one core is used to write to Kusto table, i.e., 80Gb is writing with only one core and remaining cores are in idle state.
This process takes good amount of 20-25 mins and we have tight SLA of 10 mins.

Azure databricks(28GB RAM and 8 CPU cores each- 5 nodes)

Each file size is of ~260MB uncompressed and in parquet format. I also seen some best practices document where it says file size should be between 100MB to 1 GB uncompressed.

Using writestream API in databricks to write the data.

What is the ideal approach to write the data from ADLS to ADX in distributed way using spark-connector ?

Comment: Hi. There are too many open / unclear points in this scenario. May I suggest a direct communication with the Kusto product group?

Answer (score 1):

First - the most efficient flow from ADLS storage to ADX is EventGrid, as the writing through the Spark connector means data is translated to Spark internal and then to csv which is sent to ADX. From the conversation with you guys it was clear you are using Spark for transforming the data before ingestion, in that case the Spark connector is a good choice.
From version 3.1.0 the connector flow got split by default into three Jobs (unless writeMode.Queued - is used), the first translates data into csv, writes it to storage, and queue and ingestion for ADX, this is done in distributed fashion. The second stage is polling on these ingestions until all finishes successfully to ensure transactionality, this is done using one core as the operation is really cheap (call to table storage) and there's no need to hold more than one worker for that. Third stage is sealing the transaction (this is metadata operation in ADX) - and therefore also needs one core.